# Таймер обратного отсчёта C#

Tags: c#

Всем добрый вечер! Мне нужно сделать таймер обратного отсчёта 10 минут. В форме есть кнопка button1, после нажатия кнопки запустить таймер. Время должно отображаться в Label1. Можете написать кусочек кода? Буду очень признательна!

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать официальное учебное руководство на эту тему от Microsoft : https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd492144.aspx

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Извините, но не могу проголосовать за переоткрытие вопроса. Привидите ваш код в вопросе. Никто не ожидает от вас законченого красивого и рабочего кода. Только то, что вы приложили усилия к его написанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве примера:

```
System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    public int counter = 10;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;//это твой интервал 1000 милисек = 1секунд
        myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Start_Game);//тут подписываемся на событие Start_Game(и каждую секунду будет отрабатывать наше событие в нем уже и твори то угодно)
        myTimer.Start();//запускаем таймер
    }

    private void Start_Game(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            if (counter!=0)
            {
                label1.Text = counter--.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                myTimer.Stop();

            }

        })); 

    }
}
```

Comment: На мой взгляд, лучше всего было бы дать краткие выжимки по задаче - как работать с таймером. Ваш пример принес еще один нераскрытый пункт, это многопоточное окружение, взаимодействие с UI из разных потоков. Хотя бы описать как это работает и почему нужно так делать - это было бы куда полезнее.

Comment: @AlexKuznetsov спасибо за замечание, учту в будущем.